# Spring boot upload zip files slow

Tags: spring, performance, spring-boot, upload, zip

I am using Spring boot upload files to server.I found something weird.when I upload a Jpg file with 4.88MB ,it takes 8.47s,but a 3.16M zip file,it takes about 1.3min. Considering this compressed file contains over 900 small files. I changed another zip file contains 10 small files.Now it takes 33.96s to transfer data even this new zip file is 6.52M,more lager then the old.

So does the number of files in the zip file affect the upload speed? If so, why?

application.yml:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 20MB
```

java:

```
@RequestMapping("/changeMainAttachment")
@ResponseBody
public Object addChangeMainAttachment(@RequestParam("changeMainAttachment[]") MultipartFile[] files){
    String fileSavePath = gunsProperties.getFileUploadPath();
    for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID() + "#_#_#" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        try {

            logger.info("file uploaded to: " + fileSavePath + fileName);
            multipartFile.transferTo(new File(fileSavePath + fileName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BusinessException(BizExceptionEnum.UPLOAD_ERROR);
        }

    }
    return new Msg();   

}
```

At the front side,I use [Bootstrap File-input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)

js:

```
initFileInput: function(select,_url,_showZone,_async,befordUpload,afterUploaded){
        var i = $(select).fileinput({
            theme: "gly",
            uploadUrl: _url,
            dropZoneEnabled: _showZone,
            uploadAsync: _async,
            showUpload: true,
            showUploadedThumbs: true,
            maxFileSize: 20*1024,
            maxFileCount: 5, 
            msgFilesTooMany: "选择上传的文件数量({n}) 超过允许的最大数值{m}！",
            hideThumbnailContent: true // hide image, pdf, text or other content in the thumbnail preview
        });
        if(befordUpload && typeof befordUpload == 'function'){
            i.on('filebatchpreupload',befordUpload);
        }
        if(afterUploaded && typeof afterUploaded == 'function'){
            i.on('filebatchuploadcomplete',afterUploaded);
        }


    }
```

I call this method by the following way

```
ChangeAdd.initFileInput("#changeMainAttachment", /change/changeMainAttachment", true, true, ChangeAdd.fileBeforeUpload, ChangeAdd.fileAfterUploaded);
```

Comment: Are you sure no other process intercepts the request from client to server? E.g antivirus, firewall, etc?